# How to add Node.js route to Google Domain?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, routes

I have a website that I created using WebFlow and it is linked to mydomain.com which I purchased on Google Domains, all is working well.

I also have a Node.js app that is hosted on Heroku which I want to be available on mydomain.com/admin.

Is this possible to set up on Heroku? I tried to set it up using the subdomain but that does not work and using the mydomain.com will take the user to the "/" page of my Node.js app rather than the WebFlow page.

What would I need to be able to set this up?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to use a subdomain for your nodejs app, something like `admin.mydomain.com`

typically when you code a nodejs app and your own frontend (whether it is written in React/ Angular / Vue / plain old html css and javascript ) you would configure them using nginx and each is assigned to the same ip address but different port (I have answered something similar for Laravel and React which configuring them on different port so same concept but change the technologies to fit your needs [Deploy Laravel and React spa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466376/deploy-laravel-and-react-spa/56466981?noredirect=1#comment99534446_56466981))

or you might code the frontend to render from the backend (server side rendering something like Nextjs https://nextjs.org/ which let you server side render React)

this changes a bit when you use an external service like WebFlow

the `mydomain.com` is configured to work with your WebFlow website, I don't know how it is configured but I assume that it is configured in a way that WebFlow reference your CNAME and A name to work with your WebFlow site flawlessly so it is configured like CNAME refers to `mydomain.webflow.com` and A refers to the ip address of the server of the WebFlow site (read more about it here https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-a-cname-records/)

so you refer `www.mydomain.com` to your WebFlow page

and you refer `admin.mydomain.com` to your nodejs app hosted on heroku

to answer the question of "why I can't just refer my nodejs app using `mydomain.com/admin`" :

back trace the references: the DNS server will refer `mydomain.com` to the WebFlow site so when you type `mydomain.com` on the browser, it would refer to the ip address of the WebFlow site

assume the WebFlow site's ip address is 10.10.10.1
and your nodejs app heroku ip address is 20.20.20.1

when you type `mydomain.com/admin` and it is referenced to the WebFlow site, it is as if typing `10.10.10.1/admin`

to achieve the part of having `10.10.10.1/admin` refer to the nodejs app, they both should be on the same server and configured on different ports but under the same ip address

but since they are not, so it won't be achieved as you would expect

also don't forget maybe `/admin` is reserved for WebFlow so you might not able to use it

hope my answer helped a bit

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I will give this a try today and see if I can get it working, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Deploy a simple nginx only server. Ex on digital ocean or aws. Then configure it with 2 location

/ ----- for mydomain.com

/admin ---- to your heroku app

You can perform caching load balancing also with this single nginx server.